# How to sort a list in python first depending on a value, and then depending on another value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a python list as:

```
arr = [('f', 1), ('g', 2), ('h', 3), ('a', 1), ('j', 1), ('o', 1), ('v', 2)]
```

I want to sort this list in this way:

```
arr = [('h', 3), ('g', 2), ('v', 2), ('a', 1), ('f', 1), ('j', 1), ('o', 1)]
```

That is, first I want to sort the elements of the list depending on the 2nd index of each element. So I used:

```
arr.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

It gives me this:

```
arr = [('h', 3), ('g', 2), ('v', 2), ('f', 1), ('a', 1), ('j', 1), ('o', 1)]
```

Now I further want to sort this list in **ascending order depending on the elements in first position of each tuple**, but I want to **maintain the descending order of the values of second position** of each tuple. My desired output is this-

```
arr = [('h', 3), ('g', 2), ('v', 2), ('a', 1), ('f', 1), ('j', 1), ('o', 1)]
```

Can I achieve this using one single sort() function? Or I need to use 2 sort() functions?

**I don't want to use any module. I need to use lambda expression only.**

Comment: Build a tuple that sorts naturally the way you want: `arr.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
arr = [('f', 1), ('g', 2), ('h', 3), ('a', 1), ('j', 1), ('o', 1), ('v', 2)]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[('h', 3), ('g', 2), ('v', 2), ('a', 1), ('f', 1), ('j', 1), ('o', 1)]
```